# FileProvider.getUriForFile() not correctly linking to image taken from MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: java, android, xml, uri

Sorry for the title, I was not sure how to word it, my problem with my app is taking a photo and getting its Uri content to write to a new file using input/output stream. So far I have this

```
Intent take_photo_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (take_photo_intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        try
        {
            // create file from a template
            image_file = createFileForImage();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // check if file is null
        if(image_file != null)
        {
            // create uri using file and applying a provider
            image_uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), PROVIDER, image_file);
            take_photo_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
            image_path = image_uri.getPath();
            // start activity
            startActivityForResult(take_photo_intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
```

in this case, the return bitmap is what I need to display the thumbnail quality image in my app

my issue comes with trying to get the full scaled image and save it to a custom folder in the android devices storage.

I been following this tutorial

```
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#Save%20the%20Full-size%20Photo
```

I am not 100% sure I set up the provider correctly, the app compiles and runes, my issue is with the the Uri.

if you go back to this chunk of my app

```
image_uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), PROVIDER, image_file);
take_photo_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
image_path = image_uri.getPath();
```

the image_file is a File object I created in a folder in the external storage, that part is fine since i used that path for other things and can verify it in a file manager. this is not used until later.

The provider "seems to work" since the app runs

my issue is the image_uri. My thoughts is, i have a empty file saved in that dir i created, now I need to read the contents of image_uri into that file, so I did this in the onActivityResult

```
   // this will hold the Uri data
    InputStream in_file = null;
    // this will be used to write the input stream to the file
    OutputStream out_file = null;
    // check if Uri is null
    if(image_uri != null) {
        try {
            // get the Uri data into an input stream
            in_file = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(image_uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // check for nulls
        if (in_file != null && image_file != null) {
            // create output stream linked to new file location
            try {

                out_file = new FileOutputStream(image_file);
                Log.i("IMAGE", "open outsream");

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            // create temp byte array
            byte[] image_bytes = null;

            try {

                // use apache tools to write bytes to that file using the outputstream
                image_bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in_file);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (image_bytes != null && out_file != null) {
                try {

                    out_file.write(image_bytes);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now im thinking, ok, I have the picture just taken which the provider set up, I create an external file onto sd card which I know works, and I have an input stream to the uri and an outputstream to the file, and used IOUtils.toByteArray to write tho.

However, my problem is the uri data is all blank. by that i mean the bytes are all 0's or size of array after that IOUtils.toByteArray call is 0. so I am guessing it must be a problem with the provider. I am still not sure how it works, going off the tutorial, I have this

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myapp.main.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures" />
```

As I said, I am not sure how this works, is /files/Pictures a folder in my apps internal storage by default? do I have to make it?

when logging out some stuff, this is what I got

```
 image_uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), PROVIDER, image_file);
  Log.i("IMAGE", "DEBUG--->: " + image_uri.getPath());

 I/IMAGE: DEBUG--->: /my_images/camera_shots/20160808_190857-1642881770.jpg
```

and I never created that folder, so I am confused on how this all works.

Comment: Any solution you found?